# Plotly Grouped Bar Chart in RShiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, shiny, plotly

I am trying to create a grouped bar chart using Plotly and RShiny where the user can select a variable to group by and display on the xaxis (called xvar()), and a variable which splits the xaxis variable into further groups (called xsubvar()).

I am trying to display the average of the variable AVAL on the y axis.

Here is my current code:

```
barGraphGrouped <- reactive({
    
    filteredData() %>% group_by(xvar(),xsubvar()) %>% mutate(n=n_distinct(USUBJID)) %>% 
      plot_ly(x=xvar(),y=filteredData()$AVAL,type="bar",text =~paste('n =',n), textposition = 'outside',
              textfont = list(size = 14),
              transforms = list(
                list(
                  type = 'aggregate',
                  groups = xvar(),
                  aggregations = list(list(target = 'y', func = 'avg', enabled = T))
                )
              )) %>%
      add_trace(x=xsubvar(),y=filteredData()$AVAL,
                transforms = list(
                  list(
                    type = 'aggregate',
                    groups = xsubvar(),
                    aggregations = list(list(target = 'y', func = 'avg', enabled = T))
                  )
                )) %>%
      layout(barmode='group',title=paste("Average AVAL by",input$xradio),
             xaxis = list(title = input$xradio,tickfont = list(size = 13)), 
             yaxis = list(title = input$yradio,tickfont = list(size = 13)))
  })
```

This results in the following plot:
[Plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufMtD.png)

As you can see, the groups are split how I would like but the n on top of each bar and the mean AVAL is not calculating as I hoped.

I have created the exact graph I am hoping to accomplish in ggplot using the following code:

```
myplot <- filteredData() %>% group_by(xvar(),xsubvar()) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(AVAL=mean(AVAL)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x=xvar(),y=AVAL,fill=xsubvar(),label=xsubvar()))+
       geom_col(stat="identity",position = position_dodge(.9))+
       scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
       theme_classic()+
       ggtitle(paste("Average AVAL by",input$xradio,"and",input$xsubradio))+
       ylab(input$yradio)+
       xlab(input$xradio)+
       scale_x_discrete(labels=names(xvar()))+
       geom_text(position = position_dodge(.9),size=3)+
       theme(
         legend.position = "none",
         panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
       )

ggplotly(myplot) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = -0.2))
```

This generates the following plot:
[Plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2yGs.png)

However I am trying to figure out how to recreate in plotly because I prefer the visual output and customization options present in plotly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data it is hard to verify the issue.  Please try this

```
filteredData() %>% group_by(xvar(),xsubvar()) %>% mutate(n=mean(AVAL)) %>% 
  plot_ly(x=xvar(),y=n,type="bar",text =~paste('n =',n), textposition = 'outside',
          textfont = list(size = 14),
          transforms = list(
            list(
              type = 'aggregate',
              groups = xvar(),
              aggregations = list(list(target = 'y', func = 'avg', enabled = T))
            )
          ))
```